# Fix INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, android-manifest, fixed

After searching three hours on the web I couldn't find a solution for my app , I'm having an error that says : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED .. Any Help ! by the way I tried to test it before and it works great !! Any suggestions ?

This is the Manifest file :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="">
    <activity
        android:name="com.abdullahadhaim.itc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.abdullahadhaim.itc.Two"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_two" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.abdullahadhaim.itc.Three"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_three" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.abdullahadhaim.itc.Four"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_four" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.abdullahadhaim.itc.Five"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_five" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.abdullahadhaim.itc.Six"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_six" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.abdullahadhaim.itc.Seven"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_seven" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.abdullahadhaim.itc.Eight"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_eight" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.abdullahadhaim.itc.End"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_end" >
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />` ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Are you building with Gradle? Tools v0.11.+?

Comment: @kcoppock no , I'm not , but my app was working before !

Comment: IDE? Try just doing a clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your manifest file is missing those lines :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.abdullahadhaim.itc"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
```

Try to add them, then **clean-up** the project and build it